# Can $ f(c | a, b) \propto f(a | b, c) $? When?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Given that

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf f(a\mid b, c) & = \frac{\mathsf f(a,b,c)}{\mathsf f(b, c)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\mathsf f(c\mid a,b)\,\mathsf f(a, b)}{\mathsf f(b, c)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\mathsf f(c\mid a,b)\,\mathsf f(a\mid b)\,\mathsf f(b)}{\mathsf f(b, c)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\mathsf f(c\mid a,b)\,\mathsf f(a\mid b)}{\mathsf f(c\mid b)}\frac{\mathsf f(b)}{\mathsf f(b)}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\mathsf f(c\mid a,b)\;\mathsf f(a\mid b)}{\mathsf f(c\mid b)}
\end{align}$$

and assuming that there is no prior information about $a$, $b$ and $c$ and $a, b$ are mutually independent, then $ f(a\mid b) = f(a) = constant $.

Hence, can't I assume that $ f(a | b, c) \propto f(c | a, b) $?

Comment: No, for the same reason why $f(a|b) \ne f(b|a)$ in general. Do you have any specific example in mind?

Comment: what if a and b are independent and constants (as uninformative priors)? $ f(a)=f(b) $

Comment: I didn’t say it’s impossible, but as noticed in the answer below, it’s a special case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $a$ and $b$ are independent, you have:

$$\begin{align}
f(c|a,b)
&= \frac{f(a,b,c)}{f(a,b)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{f(a,b,c)}{f(b,c)} \cdot \frac{f(b,c)}{f(a,b)} \\[6pt]
&= f(a|b,c) \cdot \frac{f(b,c)}{f(a) f(b)} \\[6pt]
&= f(a|b,c) \cdot \frac{f(c|b)}{f(a)}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

So, under this condition you have the logical equivalence:

$$f(c|a,b) = f(a|b,c)
\quad \quad \quad \iff \quad \quad \quad 
f(c|b) = f(a).$$

In other words, under your independence assumption, you can still only say that $f(c|a,b) = f(a|b,c)$ if $f(c|b) = f(a)$.

Comment: Hmmm so where am I doing wrong here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459995/bayes-rule-with-3-variables-question-where-am-i-wrong-here ? Can u give it a check?

Comment: I expanded a bit more my thinking to see where I am getting it wrong. Can u give it a check? Thx